# batch file doesn't wait for ng command to finish

Tags: batch-file

I have the following batch file. I need to figure out a way to make it wait until the `ng new` command is done before it prompts for the projects to install. However, after the `ng new` command competes the script exits and never prompts me for projects to install.

```
@ECHO OFF

SET /P name=Enter Site Name: 

cd C:\Users\eric\OneDrive\Desktop\GitHub\gig_work
START /B /WAIT ng new %name%

SET /P projects=Enter The Projects To Install: 

for %%a in ("%projects:,=" "%") do (
  npm i @farley911/%%a
)
```

Comment: It kind of sounds like `ng` is another batch script and you need to use `call ng new %name%` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the windows environment, when installing angular cli, there are `ng.cmd` and `ng.ps1`, which are both relevant to Windows. and `ng`, which is in fact a `.sh` script, for Linux environment.

All of these are simply local shell scripts that initiates the `ng.js` via `nodejs`, depending on the choice of shell (`cmd`, `Powershell` or `bash/sh`).

Because you're using `ng.cmd` you need to `call` the script.

Some notes:

1. a Variable called `%onedrive%` should exist to determine your onedrive profile path, as updated below:
2. The `npm` command is better initiated if you double quote the the entire package name, though the option you used also works.

```
@echo off
pushd "%OneDrive%\Desktop\GitHub\gig_work"

set /P "name=Enter Site Name: "
call ng.cmd n "%name%"

set /P "projects=Enter The Projects To Install: "
for %%a in ("%projects:,=" "%") do call npm.cmd i "@farley911/%%~a"
popd
```

**Side note**, if you were to ever use `start` (which should not be used here) you should include a quoted comment first, even if it is empty as some OS versions explicitly expects the first quoted section to be a comment. i.e. `start "" /b /wait "executable.exe"`